# Symmetric group $S_7$ - order of an element

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Find an element $x$ in the symmetric group $S_7$ such that the order
>   of $x$ is $12$, and show that there doesn't exist an element of $S_7$
>   such that the order is greater than $12$.

I'm having some difficulties to do this problem. Is anyone is able to give me a good hint to solve this problem?

Comment: If $(x_1\,\dots\,x_k)$ and $(y_1,\dots,y_l)$ are two disjoint cycles, what is the order of $(x_1\,\dots\,x_k)(y_1,\dots,y_l)$? Once you can answer that question, you'll be able to solve your problem.

Comment: Dude you have cycles of order 1,2,3,4,5,6, and 7. If you take any two disjoint cycles of order a, and b (respectively) then their product had order ab.

Comment: The function that gives the maximum order $g(n)$ of an element in $S_n$ is sometimes called *Landau's function*, and it is the subject of https://oeis.org/A000793 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of $x$ is the lcm of the order if its disjoint cycles.

The possibilities are thus $7,lcm(2,5)=10,lcm(3,4)=12$. So nothing can have order greater than $12$.

As for finding the element, this gives us a clue. We want disjoint $3$ and $4$ cycles. Pick whatever you like.

Comment: For maximizing order of an element of $S_n$ it does not always suffice just to consider the orders of products of a $k$-cycle and an $(n - k)$-cycle. For example (I think this example is minimal), for $n = 10$, the maximal order of a product of two cycles is $3 \cdot 7 = 21$, but the maximal order of an element corresponds to a partition into three numbers, namely, $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 = 30$.

Comment: Good point. OP might want to include all possibilities to be thorough, but obviously we can only get three two cycles in this case.